# Output in Class Function

Tags: c++

i'm trying to prompt the user to key in the data and then call out the function to print out the data from a "class" function...here's my code below and it's returning strange numbers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class planet
{
public:
    int id_planet;
    float x,y,z;
};

void report_planet_properties(planet P)
{
    cout<<"Planet's ID: "<<P.id_planet<<endl;
    cout<<"Planet's coordinates (x,y,z): ("<<P.x<<","<<P.y<<","<<P.z<<")"<<endl;
}

void set_planet_properties(planet Q)
{
    cout<<"Enter planet's ID: ";
    cin>>Q.id_planet;
    cout<<"Enter planet's coordinates (x,y,z): ";
    cin>>Q.x>>Q.y>>Q.z;
}

int main()
{
    planet G;
    set_planet_properties(G);
    report_planet_properties(G);
}
```

Comment: Pass by object vs Pass by reference...

Comment: @CPUTerminator, may as well form that into an answer.

Comment: @Chad Thought this question would be answered before I could even type that comment lol... Well... There is an answer now.

Comment: You can make your function to return that object or make it to accept a pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty simple: you are passing by value instead of by reference. This means that your functions receive a **copy** of the object you pass, not the object itself. This is not a big problem with `report_planet_properties()`, since it will not change the value of the object received (though you are doing an unnecessary copy), but `set_planet_properties()` will just change the value of the copy received, not the original object.

The fix is very simple. Just declare your functions this way:

```
void report_planet_properties(const planet& P) // Pass a reference that will not be modified
void set_planet_properties(planet& Q) // Pass a reference that may be modified
```

If you don't know what are references, you need to read a basic C++ book. Basically, this is the mechanism to pass objects instead of copies of the objects, as I said before.

Answer (score 1):

This function accepts object planet by value:

```
void set_planet_properties(planet Q)
```

so when you make this call:

```
set_planet_properties(G);
```

when function called local copy of object is created, you modify fields of that copy and when function terminates that copy is gone. So simple solution would be to pass object by pointer or reference:

```
void set_planet_properties(planet &Q) // reference
void set_planet_properties(planet *Q) // pointer
```

reference in this case is preferred.

But even better solution would be to make `report_planet_properties` and `set_planet_properties` to be class methods.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are passing the object by value to the method `set_planet_properties(planet Q)` and `report_planet_properties(planet P)` , each methods have their own copy of `Planet` object which is local to that method only. Hence the changes made to that copy are **not visible** outside that method .

You can pass the pointer to the object these methods like this

```
void report_planet_properties(planet *P);
void set_planet_properties(planet *Q);
```

and in the `main` method , pass the address of the object .

```
set_planet_properties(&G);
report_planet_properties(&G);
```

This makes the same object to be passed in both the methods and hence the modifications to that object are **visible** outside those methods also.

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are pretty complete. This is an alternate solution just to mention:

```
class planet{
public:
    int id_planet;
    float x,y,z;

    planet() : id_planet(0),x(0),y(0),z(0) {}
};

planet set_planet_properties(planet Q)
{
    cout<<"Enter planet's ID: ";
    cin>>Q.id_planet;
    cout<<"Enter planet's coordinates (x,y,z): ";
    cin>>Q.x>>Q.y>>Q.z;

    return Q;
}

void main()
{
    planet G;
    G = set_planet_properties(G);
    report_planet_properties(G);
}
```

You can return that object by your function too.